# Should I actively fight as Torbjörn as far as damage output is concerned?

Tags: overwatch

I find that setting up a turret near a wall and mostly repairing it while hiding from enemies is a viable (while extremely cheesy) tactic. However, should I try to support my turret with my rivet gun to get more damage or is it most efficient to keep my turret up at all times to maximize it's single-life efficiency and use my gun for defense alone? Is there a huge benefit to actively fighting as Torbjörn or should I rely on the turret?

Comment: Although against the rules I'll give you my take on the matter: I tought of that(constantly banging it with my hammer and let it do the job) but it simply doesn't work. It's a stationary target thus very easy once they see it, and it makes quite a good DPS so its a high priority target. The amount of heal the hammer does is not comparable to the risk you take to keep it alive. The best start here is to erect it somewhere hidden and behind your tanks, and support it by being a moving target and have the enemy shoot at you and your team before they notice the turret.

Comment: @ИвоНедев I don't believe it's against the rules since I'm asking for a strategy to maximize damage done to enemy players, not what's the "best" way to play Torbjörn. Otherwise, I can see the pluses in taking fire away from the turret and using it as a defensive structure, rather than a single form of attack.

Comment: By against the rules I believe it might be too opinion based. In any case I hate leaving answers unanswered just because they are not 100% on the rules that's why I left the rest of my comment. If it is, infact on the rules, then NVM me.

Comment: @ИвоНедев This sort of question is very much not against the rules. See the post about [the difference between Good Subjective and Bad Subjective](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/). This is a situation that calls for expertise based on personal experience and/or references and is thus perfectly valid to ask here, hence why I would also disagree with the close votes on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Torbjorn's Rivet Gun is an extremely potent weapon in both CQC and long range.  As a Torbjorn player I have two strategies:

- Abuse his primary fire (single shot) to the max. Chip damage, regardless of how much damage it does, builds your ultimate meter faster, and due to the highly predictable arc and range it is your go to weapon.  You can spam it down hallways, spam it down chokepoints, and if you know where the enemies are, it's an easy way to gain free meter without exposing yourself to too much danger.
- His secondary fire is really only used in CQC, or close situations. Torbjorn is an interesting hero because his small frame lends him a small hitbox.  When I see, for example, an opposing Reinhardt somewhat low on HP, I like to fill up on armor if I have the spare scrap, then charge underneath his shield, then right click to go "full combat".  It's deadly at close range but not much else in mid-long range.
- In Molten Core, his primary fire firerate becomes insanely fast, so you can really do some heavy damage if you can lead your shots well against big heroes like Reinhardt, Winston, or Roadhog.

IN general, you should be:

- Setting up your turret that is hard for the defenders to counter, meaning putting it flush against a wall to perhaps cover one side of it, then let it build meter for you since his turret will do that automatically
- Stay close to it so you can repair when it gets damaged, but keep an eye out for enemy positions so you can be ready to ambush them when they try to get the jump on you and your turret.   Especially against hard hitting CQC heroes, like Reaper and Tracer.

Some other tips:

- The reality is that his turret is not a combat focused weapon. It's used to chip opponents away so your team's heavy hitters can clean up.   In Molten Core, this changes and thus you can focus on combat
- On payload maps I like to work with a Reinhardt to allow me to setup the turret on the payload cart and have him block incoming damage.  This allows for really easy meter gain and kills by working together with him.
- Play other heroes against enemy Torbjorn to get a sense of where they place turrets and where it can be used to max potential.  Over time I've come to learn of good spots that are both well protected and can cover specific chokepoints

Comment: This seems pretty accurate. I have a friend who plays Torbjorn more than any other hero, and this is what works for him. The gun can be very damaging if used appropriately, but the turret comes first.

Comment: So working towards building Ultimate meter is the way to go? Great! Thanks!

Comment: @DGarvanski Yeah, since Ultimate gives you tons of HP and gives your turret tons of DPS. But don't activate Ultimate just to go CQB, ultimately you should be saving it for say when your turret is low on hp but there are plenty of enemies around that it can kill, etc.

Comment: I take it CQC = "Close Quarters Combat".  But what is "CQB"?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Close Quarters Battle. Same thing.